# How can I install Windows Installer 3.0 on a Windows Web Server 2008 machine?

Tags: windows-installer

I need to install Windows Installer 3.0 on a machine running Windows Web Server 2008 R2. When I try the redistributable, it says that there isn't enough space available to complete the operation. I've got over 100GB free, so obviously that's not the problem. Running as an admin doesn't help.

How can I install Windows Installer 3.0 on this machine?